# NHibernate Multiple Database Schema Reference to App_Data

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to do Multiple database connection where the main database is attached to SQL Server instance eg: (local) and another database is located in ASP.NET App_Data or it just a silly idea?

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, that's possible. Note that, by using a database in App_Data, there is a great chance that you will have to struggle with security-related errors when running your app on IIS in production environment.

If it's a silly idea or not, depends on the intended usage of that app. IMHO, if it's a demo site to be run on a laptop during a meeting, why not. There is already a discussion on this matter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755/asp-net-performance-implications-of-a-sql-server-database-in-the-app-data-folde).